# Oracle Control and Webserver

Tags: oracle, web-server

How does the Database Control work, since Apache is not running on this computer? The Url says https://localhost:1158/em/console/logon/logon. I do have a WAMP apache server on here but I have to shut it down to get the Oracle Control to work , other wise I get a 404. 
Thanks

Comment: it uses J2EE rather than apache AFAIK. no idea why you can't get both to work at the same time given they are on different ports though...

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned by @Jack Douglas, Oracle Application Server (a J2EE container) is installed. You may want to do a tcpdump to see what applications are running on conflicting ports. You can find a list of ports used by Database Control here: [Managing Oracle Port Numbers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/app_port.htm).

Some ports used by Enterprise Manager Database Control:

- 1158 - Http Port for Oracle Enterprise Manager Console.
- 3938 - Oracle Management Agent.
- 5520 - RMI port for Enterprise Manager Console.
- 5540 - JMS Port for Enterprise Manager Console.